Generate a link from custom fields
I am trying to integrate 2 prducts, but im not sure on how to do it.
when a new contact is added i would like for a button/link to go to another page, which will then generate a digital pass using the URL.
this URL would be https://example.com/integration/createpass/c317b438-81fb-4015-a212-fa9609c11e16?membershipno=Value%20for%20membershipno&name=Value%20for%20name&DOB=Value%20for%20DOB&CountyOffice=Value%20for%20CountyOffice&ADName=Value%20for%20ADName&ADDOB=Value%20for%20ADDOB&ADColour=Value%20for%20ADColour&ADCHIP=Value%20for%20ADCHIP&hearing=Value%20for%20hearing&bbd=Value%20for%20bbd&non-verbal=Value%20for%20non-verbal&Mobility=Value%20for%20Mobility&medical%20alert=Value%20for%20medical%20alert&invisible-disabilities=Value%20for%20invisible-disabilities&training=Value%20for%20training&expirationDate=2025-01-01%2015%3A00
but I would like for the fields to be automatically completed using the information I supplied when the contact was added. How would I do this please?

Are you sure you need to expose this integration to the UI? Or is it sufficient to call that url from behind the scenes to obtain the response from the external service?

it would only be accesible to admin backend. I just dont really want to have to do it all manually for everyone

Some options:
1 Make a message template with the url and include tokens for the custom fields, e.g. {contact.custom_27} (use the tokens dropdown when composing the template to see them).
2(a) Install civirules. Get it to trigger on new contact and send you an email using that message template. Or I can't remember if it can create an activity with specific details but if so you could get it to do that.
OR
2(b) After creating the contact, choose print/merge document and use your message template. Click preview or save. The pdf will contain your link. If you click save the pdf will be saved in an activity. Or instead of print/merge you could send an email using your template.

But is there a way to make the link it generated be a button on the contact screen rather than in an activity?
